# run broadleafcommerce DemoSite failed, http://localhost:8983/solr/catalog_reindex not found

Tags: solr, broadleaf-commerce

when i tried to run it locally in idea(not changing any code) as the
https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/getting-started/running-locally. Do i need to configure anything special for solr?

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report 
re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-12-24 19:11:52.356 ERROR 30234 --- [           main]         o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error
from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/catalog_reindex: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/catalog_reindex/update. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p>
</body>
</html>
```

And I couldn't find solrconfig.xml and schema.xml in site/src/main/resources folder.

Comment: Because I started the solr out of the project previously which led to embedded solr failed. I killed all the solr services and restarted in admin package. It's ok now. And I found those files in SolrStart.jar.

Comment: you need to manually download the solar and place it in the temp directory and re run